# IntelliSense for Ajax and JavaScript libraries in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I know about using a -vsdoc.js file for [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense), and the one for jQuery is easy to find. What other JavaScript, Ajax, and DHTML libraries have them and where can  I find those files? Also, is there a document which outlines the specifications for -vsdoc.js files?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An excellent blog posting from Betrand LeRoy on IntelliSense format for JavaScript: 
*[The format for JavaScript doc comments](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2007/04/23/the-format-for-javascript-doc-comments.aspx)*.

In a nutshell:

Summary - used to describe a function/method or event. Syntax:

```
<summary locid="descriptionID">Description</summary>
```

Parameter - describe a parameter to a function/method. Syntax:

```
<param name="parameterName"
    mayBeNull="true|false" optional="true|false"
    type="ParameterType" parameterArray="true|false"
    integer="true|false" domElement="true|false"
    elementType="ArrayElementType" elementInteger="true|false"
    elementDomElement="true|false"
    elementMayBeNull="true|false">Description</param>
```

The param tag is used to describe the parameters of a method or constructor. The param tags should be in the same order as the method or constructor's parameters and have the same names.

Function return type - syntax:

```
<returns
    type="ValueType" integer="true|false" domElement="true|false"
    mayBeNull="true|false" elementType="ArrayElementType"
    elementInteger="true|false" elementDomElement="true|false"
    elementMayBeNull="true|false">Description</returns>
```

Value type - describes a property (shouldnt use 'summary' for a prop) - syntax:

```
<value
    type="ValueType" integer="true|false" domElement="true|false"
    mayBeNull="true|false" elementType="ArrayElementType"
    elementInteger="true|false" elementDomElement="true|false"
    elementMayBeNull="true|false"
    locid="descriptionID">Description</value>
```

Field - used to describe a field in a JavaScript class - syntax:

```
<field name="fieldName" type="FieldType"
    integer="true|false" domElement="true|false" mayBeNull="true|false"
    elementType="ArrayElementType" elementInteger="true|false"
    elementDomElement="true|false" elementMayBeNull="true|false"
    locid="descriptionID">Description</field>
```

How to include IntelliSense for an external JavaScript file, the following syntax as the first line(s) in a JavaScript file:

```
<reference path="path/to/the/script/reference.js"
    assembly="Assembly.Name" name="ScriptResourceName.js"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote on article to sum up (from investigation) what parts of vsdoc are used to help Intellisense in VS 2010 : http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/2010/08/vs-2010-vs-doc-and-javascript-intellisense/

Answer (score 0):

You can find Intellisense for MooTools here: http://code.google.com/p/mootoolsintellisense/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

Some guy built a very nice [**vsdoc for Google Maps V3**](http://gmapvsdoc.codeplex.com/). I use it, it works well. ;-)