# How can I create my own vsdoc.js file for my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, vsdoc

How can I create a vsdoc.js file for an existing JavaScript library that will provide intellisense detail inside of Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282129/intellisense-for-ajax-and-javascript-libraries-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just create the same functions and objects that are in the library, but [add XML comments](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2007/04/23/the-format-for-javascript-doc-comments.aspx) to them.