# Need intellisense or autocomplete feature for my own javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Jquery comes with a vsdoc file that help us to get intellisense or autocomplete feature for jquery. if i want to have the same intellisense or autocomplete feature for my own javascript file then what i need to do.....please help. thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create my own vsdoc.js file for my JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267134/how-can-i-create-my-own-vsdoc-js-file-for-my-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comment your code with JSDoc rules, then use this tool to convert it to VSDoc.

http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit-vsdoc/

or learn VSdoc:

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2007/04/23/the-format-for-javascript-doc-comments.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Create a vsdoc file for your javascript and include it in your project in the same location as the .js file.

Comment: I voted to close this question.  See comment that contains a link to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need vsdocs. In my opinion, it's easier to just document your files using the [vsdoc instructions](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2007/04/23/the-format-for-javascript-doc-comments.aspx). If you then minify and compile your JavaScript files for release using a tool like [Google's Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/), comments and vsdoc remarks are automatically removed for you. This eliminates the need to maintain two separate files. You can even set the Closure compiler to run automatically when you build your VS project.

You'll also need to reference your JavaScript files to enable the IntelliSense. Place

```
/// <reference path="SomeJavaScript.js" />
```

at the top of each JavaScript file.