# Javascript and VS2012 Intellisense

Tags: javascript, webforms, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I am new to Visual Studio 2012 and Javscript coding. I have two questions i could not find answers on the web:

1. i have a webforms project and added some js-files to the sript-folder (http://raphaeljs.com/). Now i want to have Intellisense support for that js-library i added. Is that possible?
2. for what is the "_references.js" file in the scripts folder? I added all the js-library files to that file but it doesn't enable intellisense.

regards

Comment: I don't know what changes vs2012 has made, but in general intellisense is not easy to do for javascript (and other dynamically typed languages) as you can define functions anywhere, and redefine functions anywhere, in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about Visual Studio 2012, but in 2010, if you drag one JavaScript file onto another one it will add a `/// <reference name="MyScript.js" />` line at the top of the second file. If the file being referenced is documented you will get quite useful intellisense, though it is still handy even if not for just being able to explore the surface of the API.

There is some good information in this question: [IntelliSense for Ajax and JavaScript libraries in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282129/intellisense-for-ajax-and-javascript-libraries-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

To put it short, Visual Studio is terrible at intelli-sense for javascript. It is still light years behind other IDEs like IntelliJ & WebStorm.

A work around to slap it in line would be to use ReSharper which is a plugin but you need to pay for the license :(

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @DanyZift - I'm a program manager at Microsoft on the Visual Studio JavaScript tools team - have you worked with the new JavaScript IntelliSense support in Visual Studio 2012? I'd be curious to hear how you think we could make it better. Here's a blog post discussing the new features, too: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2012/05/10/my-favorite-features-improved-tooling-in-visual-studio-11-for-javascript-developers.aspx