# function methods and parameters not appearing in "." reference

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, code-assist

Update: See self-answer below, which says, this is a visual studio javascript intellisense issue, which requires a "reference path" solution, and provides a specific solution.  The original question led off in the wrong direction.

=======original question below===========================

I've built the below to store and retrieve height and width values for different panes in an VS2013 MVC view.  `PaneDims` contains an array (`pncnfgar`) of `pconfig` objects. I'd like to use `PaneDims` as globally available object that I can access the methods and parameter of using `"."` notation, e.g `PaneDims.getconfig`.  I'd like to use `pconfig` as an instantiable object that I can fill from `PaneDims.getconfig` and then also access the parameters of using `"."` notation, eg. `wrk_pconfig.id`.

```
//=========================

var pconfig = function () {
this.id = ""
this.mh = 0
this.mw = 0
this.lh = 0
this.lw = 0
this.dh = 0
this.dw = 0
}
//========================================
var PaneDims = new function () {
this.currPaneConfig = "";
this.pcnfgar = [];
this.getconfig = function (id) {
    for (i = 0; i < this.pcnfgar.length; i++) {
        if (this.pcnfgar[i].id === id) {
            return this.pcnfgar[i];
        }
    }
}
}
//===================================
function TestPaneDims() {
CreatePaneDimsClass()
SetInitialPanelDims()
}
//====================================
function CreatePaneDimsClass() {
//var PaneDims = new PaneDims;
LoadPanelConfigs();
}
//===========================================
```

I've omitted the details of `LoadPanelConfigs` because it all works and it's not the problem.

The problem is after I run `CreatePaneDimsClass`, then in another script file, when I try to invoke PaneDims in `SetInitialPanelDims()`,

```
//================================
function SetInitialPanelDims() {

    PaneDims.currPaneConfig = "dh1w1"
    wrkpc = new pconfig
    wrkpc = PaneDims.getconfig(PaneDims.currPaneConfig)

    b = wrkpc.id
    d = wrkpc.mh
    d = wrkpc.mw
}
//===============================
```

Again, this all works from a processing standpoint.

The issue is that when I'm writing the code the `"."` values don't appear.  e.g. I'm typing

```
b = wrkpc.
```

and I would like to see a list of `pconfig` parameters appear to select from.

So, am I mistaken that this is possible (been eating too much intellisense in C#)?
Or is there something missing that I need to do to make what I want happen?

UPDATE:  the `.` referencing works if the `SetInitialPanelDims` function is in the same script file as the other code, but not if it is in a difference script file.

So, how might I get the `.` referencing to work if the `PaneDims` function is invoked in a separate script file?

UPDATE:  Tried creating `PaneDims` with prototype and instantiation;  works fine for processing, but does not solve the code writing issue

```
function pPaneDims() { }
pPaneDims.prototype.pcnfgar = [];
pPaneDims.prototype.currPaneConfig;
pPaneDims.prototype.getconfig = function (id) {
    for (i = 0; i < this.pcnfgar.length; i++) {
        if (this.pcnfgar[i].id === id) {
            return this.pcnfgar[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try putting the fields on the functions prototype.

Comment: I tried your code, and it is working ...

Comment: So all this long block of code and long explanation and this is an Intellisense typing completion question, not a javascript language question?

Comment: @jfriend - maybe, I don't know.

Comment: @Toni, thanks, that helped clarify.  Another variable...the SetInitialPanelDims provides the . reference if the function is in the same script file, but not if in a separate script file.  So, then the question is (I'll edit it to be about a separate script file).

Comment: If `PaneDims` is supposed to be a constructor, it’s still a function, and you shouldn’t write `var PaneDims = new function () …`.

Comment: @minitech - thanks for the input. It works without the var, however, doesn't solve the problem of . referencing not working in separate script file

Comment: @Musa:  tried assembling PaneDims using prototype and instantiation; no joy (see edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a visual studio javascript intellisense issue, which requires a "reference path" solution.  That is, to add a comment line like this  (THREE forward slashes):

```
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/020_DRAFT/MyScript.js" />
```

at the top of the JS files that you want to have intellisense access to the things in MyScript.js.

The triggering clue was in here.

[Javascript and VS2012 Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769258/javascript-and-vs2012-intellisense)

I did not understand what was meant by " drag one JavaScript file onto another one " but just writing the reference statement worked fine.

Reminds me of a "using" statement in C#.

[How to reference multiple files for javascript IntelliSense in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448119/how-to-reference-multiple-files-for-javascript-intellisense-in-vs2010)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx

http://gurustop.net/blog/2012/03/03/javascript-js-intellisense-auto_complete-in-visual-studio-11-beta-the-web-_references-js-file/

This makes this question more or less irrelevant as it was originally worded.